# Запятая в предложении: "Человек, уснувший прямо на стуле в комнате(,) ни в какую не желал проснуться"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

В каком варианте правильно стоит запятая?

1. Человек, уснувший прямо на стуле в комнате, ни в какую не желал проснуться.
2. Человек, уснувший прямо на стуле в комнате ни в какую не желал проснуться.

Тут причастный оборот, но меня смутило это "ни в какую".

Comment: Оборот не деепричастный, а  причастный. Я исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

Человек, **уснувший прямо на стуле в комнате**, ни в какую не желал проснуться.

Обособляется причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

Наречное выражение ***ни в какую*** (=никак) к обороту не относится: *не желал проснуться  ни в какую.*

Вариант редактирования:  Человек, **уснувший в комнате прямо на стуле**, ни в какую не желал проснуться.